# To open a clicked Image in main activity to another activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am able to open my image from SD card in gridview and also able to pass image path to another activity by using following codes:

```
package com.example.sdcardimage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Imageshow extends Activity {


    private Cursor cursor;
    private int columnIndex;
     TextView text;
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main1);  
       text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        // Set up an array of the Thumbnail Image ID column we want
        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID};
        // Create the cursor pointing to the SDCard
        cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                projection, // Which columns to return
                null,       // Return all rows
                null,
                MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID);
        // Get the column index of the Thumbnails Image ID
        columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID);


        GridView sdcardImages = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.sdcard);
        sdcardImages.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        // Set up a click listener
      sdcardImages.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                // Get the data location of the image
                String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                cursor = managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        projection, // Which columns to return
                        null,       // Return all rows
                        null,
                        null);
                columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                // Get image filename
                 String imagePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                 text.setText(imagePath);
                 Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), preview.class);
                 i.putExtra("Value1", imagePath);
                         startActivity(i);

                }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Adapter for our image files.
     */
    private class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;

        public ImageAdapter(Context localContext) {
            context = localContext;
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return cursor.getCount();
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
        {
            ImageView picturesView;
            if (convertView == null) 
            {
                picturesView = new ImageView(context);
                // Move cursor to current position
                cursor.moveToPosition(position);
                // Get the current value for the requested column
                int imageID = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
                // Set the content of the image based on the provided URI
                picturesView.setImageURI(Uri.withAppendedPath(
                        MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, "" + imageID));
                picturesView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                picturesView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
                picturesView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(100, 100));
            }
            else 
            {
                picturesView = (ImageView)convertView;
            }
            return picturesView;
        }
    }
 }
```

Now when I use the path obtained from the above code to open an image in imageView it gives me null pointer exception my code for opening image in another activity using the path obtained is as follow:

```
package com.example.sdcardimage;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class preview extends Activity
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        ImageView picture = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imagepath);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras == null) {
            return;
        }
        String value1 = extras.getString("Value1");
        if (value1 != null)
        {
        TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText(value1);
        FileInputStream in;
        BufferedInputStream buf;    
    try{ 
        in = new FileInputStream(value1);
        buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(buf);
        Bitmap bMapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, 150, 100, true);
        picture.setImageBitmap(bMapScaled);
        if (in != null) 
        {
            in.close();
           }
            if (buf != null) {
            buf.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error reading file", e.toString());
        }
       }
    }
}
```

Why am I getting null pointer exception and not able to display image in imageView?

My log is as follow

```
11-15 13:59:14.764: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-15 13:59:14.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sdcardimage/com.example.sdcardimage.preview}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 13:59:14.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
11-15 13:59:14.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2284)
11-15 13:59:14.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:112)
11-15 13:59:14.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1692)
11-15 13:59:14.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-15 13:59:14.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-15 13:59:14.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3948)
11-15 13:59:14.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-15 13:59:14.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-15 13:59:14.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:782)
11-15 13:59:14.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:540)
11-15 13:59:14.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-15 13:59:14.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-15 13:59:14.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823):     at com.example.sdcardimage.preview.onCreate(preview.java:32)
11-15 13:59:14.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1123)
11-15 13:59:14.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2231)
11-15 13:59:14.814: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(823):     ... 11 more
```

### Update

I got the output as what I was looking for, so I am posting my modified code of second activity as follow, so that it will help others who are looking for the same thing:

```
package com.example.sdcardimage;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class preview extends Activity
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String filename = extras.getString("Value1");
        FileInputStream is = null;
        BufferedInputStream bis = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
            ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);    
            } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            //Try to recover
        }
        finally {
            try {
                if (bis != null) {
                    bis.close();
                }
                if (is != null) {
                    is.close();
                }    
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the logcat log with the exception details.

Comment: have you checked your imagepath you are getting in next activity? and the same path works to show you the image in previous activity??

Comment: i had checked the path in the first activity it is the same which i get in second activity when i used to display the imagepath in textview as shown in code...

Comment: MByD i had just added my log into my code please check it out and reply me.

Comment: Friends thnks for help but i got the output as per my requirements..i have edited my code so that it can help others u wants the same output..Thnks 1nce again for helping me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
String filename = extras.getString("filename");
Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filename);
ImageView myimage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
myimage.setImageBitmap(originalBitmap);
```

final solution

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String filename = extras.getString("Value1");
    FileInputStream is = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    try {
        is = new FileInputStream(new File(filename));
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.preview);
        image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);    
        } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        //Try to recover
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (bis != null) {
                bis.close();
            }
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }    
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: use different cursors in the Imageshow  activity ( inside onItemClickListener and before that.., i made changes in ur code check it once..

Comment: I m not getting the changes which u had done in my code please can u point out by writing comment before those changes in my code...

Comment: thnks for yourhelp but i got the output as per my requirements..i have also edited my code so that it can help others u wants the same output...Thnks 1nce again for helping me

Comment: i will edited my answer as u done i n above, accept it will be useful for others..